# My code is showing an error when connecting to the database:"Error connecting to databaseAccess denied for use 'root'@'localhost(using password:YES)"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database

Please, help. I'm not being granted access to my database through localhost, but the username and password is correct. My code is showing an error when connecting to the database. I need help with the syntax for connecting to the database.
Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DPUruNet;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing;

namespace UareUBiometrics
{
  class HelperFunctions
  {
  private static Fmd[] fmds;

  private static Fmd[] allDBFmds;
  public static Fmd[] GetAllFmds
  {
  get { return allDBFmds; }

  } 

  private static string[] allUserNames;
  public static string[] GetAllUserNames
  {
  get { return allUserNames; }
  }

  private static int[] allfingerIDs;
  public static int[] GetallfingerIDs
  {
  get { return allfingerIDs; }
  }

  public static MySqlDataReader ConnectDBnExecuteSelectScript(string Script)
  {
  string connectionString = "server=localhost;User Id=root;database=customerinfo;Password=";
  MySqlDataReader dataReader = null;
  MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
  try
  {
  conn.Open();
  MySqlCommand sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(Script, conn);
  dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

  }
  catch (MySqlException ex)
  {
  MessageBox.Show("Error opening connection" + ex.Message);
  }

  return dataReader;
  }
```

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql

Answer (score 0):

Try this connection string:

```
string connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=customerinfo;Uid=root;Pwd=;";
```

Comment: “Error connecting to databaseAccess denied for use 'root'@'localhost(using password:YES)”

Comment: Strange...  I think the error message should be "…… (using password:NO)" if you leave password to empty in connect string.

Comment: Yeah, but the error message is still the same, despite having no password. I'm stumped. I'm not sure if it's a problem with the SQL but I can't seem to debug it.